# react - loading external logic at runtime

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs

I would like to separate the react application so that I can load any logic (e.g. conteners / components) from an external .js file in runtime.
e.g. an additional tab that I will be able to replace with a completely different logic or, for example, add second tab only by adding the .js file (without making any changes to the main react app)

At the moment I added a component in the main react app:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Custom = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");

        script.id = "customScript";
        script.src = "/static/js/custom.js";
        script.async = false;
        script.defer = "defer";
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        
    }, [props.match.params.id]);


    return (
        <>
            <div value={props.match.params.id} id="customRoot"></div>
        </>
    );


}

export default Custom;
```

Custom.js file is compiled using webpack from the following js files:

index.js in external application:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('customRoot')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js in external application:

```
import React from "react";
import SubFirst from "./SubSites/Sub1";
import SubSec from "./SubSites/Sub2";
import { Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {


  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Link to="/Custom/first">FIRST</Link>
        <Link to="/Custom/sec">SEC</Link>
      </div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/Custom/first' component={SubFirst} />
        <Route exact path='/Custom/sec' component={SubSec} />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

first and second page contains:

```
import React from 'react'

const SubFirst = () => {


    return (<div> SUB FIRST/SECOND</div>);

}
export default SubFirst;
```

At the moment I can navigate to the following paths in the main application:

- Custom/First
- Custom/Sec

After displaying the Custom/First or Custom/Sec page, the content of the components is displayed, but after clicking on the link in custom.js, the page is refreshed
only for the 1st navigation from the main app to the logic in custom.js)

Is it possible to remove the refresh of the entire application when navigating between the components: main application - external application?

At the moment the app in custom.js is like a new context and doesn't have access to the main app context.
Is it possible to access main context from an external loaded application?

Is there an easier way to load external logic into React in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

There're some ways for code splitting described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

For example, you can load a component with a lazy loading component wrapper, so this part of the code is just loaded when it's actually used. This can also include logic used inside the components.
You may need to adjust your webpack build settings and enable code splitting and chunks. When using create-react-app this should work out of the box.